# Metasploit Payloads from outside the local network

Tags: network, metasploit

I created a payload with metasploit and hacked my other computer.
But this only works within the local network, right?
I would like to know how hackers create payloads that work on targets outside the network? Even outside the city, the country, etc.
Can anyone teach me? If instead of putting my local IP in the payload, I put my public IP, will that solve it?

Comment: This isn't a security question, but a pure networking question. And one that is well-answered.

Answer (score -1):

You can use your public IP if you open up ports on your network.

Most attackers will be using a VPS though, I do not recommend opening your ports to serve malware.

Comment: Why not "opening your ports to serve malware"? And you're skipping over the ability to target in the first place. And as an answer to someone who obviously needs help understanding the networking, this is not very helpful.